# Как правильно сделать расположение фона как на макете?

Tags: html, css

Как расположить фоновую картинку с ноутбуком так, чтобы на адаптиве она смотрелась, как на макете? Ничего другого, как задать для самой секции .main {background-size: 100% 50%} я не додумался, но еще проблема в том, что видно, как расходится черный цвет на адаптиве из-за уменьшения фоновой картинки. Подскажите, как правильно сделать?

Сам сайт ilyin1ib.beget.tech

Макет https://www.figma.com/file/5H4KxRfSDOpqoOo3iNPDqc/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Различия в цвете черного

Образец из макета

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]